# virtualenv AssertionError on Mac Maverick

Tags: macos, virtualenv, pip

The virtualenv broke. I've tried updating, re-installing with pip, setuptools, virtualenv in a bunch of combinations, but nothing works. I've also used brew doctor and still no clue to the problem. Does anyone have this problem and have found a fix? Am I missing a package before installing virtualenv? 
Also, if you have similar assertionError, please comment.  Maybe we can find a solution together.
Thanks!

```
$ virtualenv test1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenv", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.11', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 820, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 980, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1176, in install_python
    copy_required_modules(home_dir, symlink)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1114, in copy_required_modules
    dst_filename = change_prefix(filename, dst_prefix)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1079, in change_prefix
    (filename, prefixes)
AssertionError: Filename /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.so does not start with any of these prefixes: ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/Users/user1/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages', '/Users/user1/.local/lib/python/2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7', '/Users/user1/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

Comment: I am having the same problem.  Looking for a solution as well.